# JavaFX 8 - How to build EXE with Maven & INNO

Tags: maven, build, exe, inno-setup, javafx-8

I have not been able to successfully find a working solution on how to configure Maven to build an EXE from JavaFX with Maven.

Projects set up with E(fx)clipse using the build.fxbuild work great, however I would prefer to have a maven project, with dependent modules rather the basic ANT builds.

I have seen some comments on ZENJAVA - but it appears that plug in has lost all traction and is pretty much dead.

Is there anything out there that can bundle an EXE from Maven?  My project is an enterprise project which will have several projects, and lots of dependencies - so I was hoping for a simple, effective way to manage all of that.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the plugin is NOT dead, just the official website was taken down due to the costs it produced.

Just look at the git-repository for further details: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin

We have some sample configurations within our testing-folder: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it

To just build the EXE-installer, you can specify an specific bundler (from version 8.1.3 and up).

To use the plugin, just put this into your build-plugins:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.your.amazing.mavenized.javafxapplication</mainClass>
                <bundler>EXE</bundler>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

disclaimer: i'm one of the maintainer of that plugin ;)

Comment: I have two questions on this post.  Looking at my solution above, what else other than the maven-ant-run plugin can be removed from my POM?  Secondly, how can I replicated this behavior to get a file in a folder at the root of app?  <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}" includes="properties/*.properties" />
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! In order to make this work, I needed to copy my resources to a slightly different folder structure like this:
${project.build.directory}/additionalResources/properties

Then in the plug in configuration I did this:
<additionalAppResources>${project.build.directory}/additionalResources</additionalAppResources>

Comment: Thats how it was intended to use this property :) there will be a testing-project for covering this use-case very soon

Comment: Hi, can I use zenjava for rcp based efxclipse application? Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34993773/2691625

Comment: @ArdeshanaMilan Never tried that, it's a post-build maven-plugin, and creates its own jar-file which might not include all required OSGi-entries inside the manifest-file :) but feel free to try and report back

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this with javafx-ant tasks.

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.myapp.application
    myApp
    jar
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    MyApp
    http://www.somecompany.com

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <javafx.version>8.0</javafx.version>
</properties>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo</id>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <!-- copy all dependencies of your app to target folder -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Main-Class>com.myApp.MainClass</Main-Class>
                        <implementation-version>1.0</implementation-version>
                        <JavaFX-Application-Class>com.myApp.MainClass</JavaFX-Application-Class>
                    </manifestEntries>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- copy the properties files to the root location -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources-1</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/properties</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>properties</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <!-- define the deploy ANT task -->
                            <taskdef name="jfxdeploy" classname="com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask"
                                classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />

                            <!-- define the JarSing ANT task -->
                            <!-- taskdef name="jfxsignjar" classname="com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXSignJarTask" 
                                classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" / -->
                            <jfxdeploy outdir="${project.build.directory}/deploy"
                                outfile="${build.finalName}" nativeBundles="all">
                                <info title="${project.name}" />
                                <!-- set the main class of your applcation -->
                                <application name="${project.name}"
                                    mainClass="com.myApp.MainClass" />
                                <resources>
                                    <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}" includes="*.jar" />
                                    <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/dependency"
                                        includes="*.jar" />
                                    <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/properties" includes="*.properties"/>
                                </resources>

                                <!-- set your jvm args -->
                                <platform>
                                    <jvmarg value="-Xms512m" />
                                    <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024m" />
                                </platform>
                            </jfxdeploy>
                            <!-- you need to generate a key yourself -->
                            <!--jfxsignjar destdir="${project.build.directory}/deploy" keyStore="path/to/your/keystore" 
                                storePass="yourPass" alias="yourAlias" keyPass="keyPass"> <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/deploy" 
                                includes="*.jar" /> </jfxsignjar -->
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-javafx</artifactId>
                    <version>${javafx.version}</version>
                    <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/ant-javafx.jar</systemPath>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>CashReceipts</finalName>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>8.40.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>customJar</groupId>
        <artifactId>custom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```